# R - avoid to show milliseconds with lubridate hms and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I have different dataframes (df), everyone with a vector of duration like this:

```
  Duration
  02:05:30
  01:00:58
  00:40:21
  00:54:26
```

What I am trying to do is to plot those durations with ggplot in the following way:

```
    df$Duration <- lubridate::hms(df$Duration)

    p <- ggplot(df, aes(Duration)) + scale_x_time("Duration") + 
    stat_bin(aes(y =..count..), bins=30, fill = 'darkblue') + 
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./nrow(df), labels=percent))
```

This works fine for 80% of the cases, however, sometimes in the plot the x-axis with the "Duration" shows time in the format "%H:%M:%S" with seconds having 6 decimal digits (i.e. 02:02:00.000000) which is not what I want (I'd like to have 02:02:00 instead). I don't know why it is doing that and why it does it only for some of the dataframes I have, and I am using *lubridate::hms* because it is the only way to handle durations greater than 24 hours (isn't it?), so I don't want to transform the data in POSIXct. 
Thank you in advance for your help, I hope I was clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have X-axis label as something like `2H 5M 30S` then you can try this approach

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

df$Duration <- hms(df$Duration)

ggplot(df, aes(period_to_seconds(Duration))) +     #converted duration to seconds for plotting
  stat_bin(aes(y = ..count..), bins = 30, fill = 'darkblue') + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./nrow(df), name = "percent")) +
  scale_x_continuous("Duration", labels = df$Duration, breaks = period_to_seconds(df$Duration)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

which plots

[image]

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Duration = c("02:05:30", "01:00:58", "00:40:21", 
"00:54:26")), .Names = "Duration", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to transform the data in POSIXct because I have to deal with durations greater than 24 hours, which are not supported by POSIXct. Is there a possibility to set labels format in scale_x_time?